GCR secret creation using golang for Kubernetes
Hey I am trying to create a secret for pulling images from my registry and every other registries are working other then gcr, below is the secret created,
.dockerconfigjson: '{"auths":{"us-south1-docker.pkg.dev":{"username": "_json_key","password":"{\"type\":\"service_account\",\"project_id\":\"....\",\"private_key_id\":\"...\",\"private_key\":\"...\\n\",\"client_email\":\"...\",\"client_id\":\"....\",\"auth_uri\":\"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth\",\"token_uri\":\"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token\",\"auth_provider_x509_cert_url\":\"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs\",\"client_x509_cert_url\":\"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/...\",\"universe_domain\":\"googleapis.com\"}"}}}'

below is the code for handling the gcp,
    case "gcr", "gcp":
        url = "gcr.io"
        if image.URL != "" {
            url = image.URL
        }
        username = "_json_key"
        // as the gcp credentials are in the form of a json interface, we need to convert it to a json object
        // so we can save the file temporarily and then read it for creating the secret
        var gcpCredentials GcpCredentials
        // gcp is in interface format, so we need to convert it to json
        gcpCredentialsJson, err := json.Marshal(image.GCPCredentials)
        if err != nil {
            logrus.Errorf("Could not marshal the gcp credentials: %s", err)
            return err
        }
        err = json.Unmarshal(gcpCredentialsJson, &gcpCredentials)
        if err != nil {
            logrus.Errorf("Could not unmarshal the gcp credentials: %s", err)
            return err
        }
        // create a json file with the gcp credentials
        err = os.WriteFile("/tmp/gcp_credentials.json", gcpCredentialsJson, 0644)
        if err != nil {
            logrus.Errorf("Could not write the gcp credentials file: %s", err)
            return err
        }
        // read the file and get the contents
        contents, err := os.ReadFile("/tmp/gcp_credentials.json")
        if err != nil {
            logrus.Errorf("Could not read the gcp credentials file: %s", err)
            return err
        }
        password = string(contents)

dockerConfigJson := fmt.Sprintf(`{"auths":{"%s":{"username": "%s","password":"%s"}}}`, url, username, password)
    logrus.Infof("Creating docker config secret: %s", dockerConfigJson)
    secret := corev1.Secret{
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{Name: fmt.Sprintf("%s-%s", secretName, strings.ToLower(image.Provider))},
        Type:       corev1.SecretTypeDockerConfigJson,
        Data:       map[string][]byte{".dockerconfigjson": []byte(dockerConfigJson)},
    }
    err := createSecret(&secret, clientset, namespace)

but every time I try to pull images using the token, I get below error,
Failed to pull image "us-south1-docker.pkg.dev/...": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "...": failed to resolve reference "...": failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status from GET request to https://us-south1-docker.pkg.dev/v2/token?scope=repository%3A...Apull&service=us-south1-docker.pkg.dev: 401 Unauthorized               

Warning  Failed     29m (x4 over 31m)    kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull                                                                                                                                                           

Warning  Failed     29m (x6 over 31m)    kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff

